# How can i add 3 fields with the Mongoose Model using pre function

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am bout to add the prelimGrade, midtermGrade, finalsGrade on my overall grade and divide it to 3. This code is giving me null value.

i have tried searching here and found a problem with the solution but the value is also giving me null.

Here is my code on my Test.js schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TestSchema = new Schema({
  prelim: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  midterm: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  finals: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  overall: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = Test = mongoose.model("tests", TestSchema);

TestSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  this.overall = (this.prelim + this.midterm + this.finals)/3;
  next();
});
```

and this is my code on my route

```
router.post("/test", (req, res) => {
  const { prelim, midterm, finals, overall } = req.body;
  const test = new Test({
    prelim,
    midterm,
    finals,
    overall
  });
  test.save().then(test => {
    res.json(test);
  });
});
```

i expect that it gives me value but it gives me null.

Comment: Does it show null in DB ???

Comment: It doesn't, But i fixed it now, Module.exports should be after the testschema

Answer (score 0):

The module.exports should be after the testSchema. This worked for me